# Misleading top tag update (+number) in case of an accept

Tags: bug, tags, profile-page, reputation-history, tag-score

One of my (Java tagged) answers was recently accepted (no upvotes, no downvotes).
There is misleading information on my profile.

It says: top tag +15 Java.

Tag scores calculations are based on up- and downvotes only... it does not matter whether an answer gets accepted or not.

It was only a reputation change, not a tag score change.

[image: Picture attached.]

Comment: There shouldn't be a number to the left of the tag there at all. That looks like maybe the reputation change number which is supposed to be up above next to your reputation ended up on another line somehow. Could you get a screenshot of the entire box?

Comment: @animuson, thanks. Ssh added.

Comment: I don't understand how you can make it show your top tag there. For me the only options are to track the next privilege or the next tag badge. I can't find an option to only show the top tag...

Comment: @TinyGiant, afaik there is no badge progress in case of an accept. Only up to downvotes ratio matter.

Comment: @TinyGiant, click on the little cog wheel on the right (shown in the picture). You can choose whether you want to track your next badge or privilege.

Comment: Oh weird, ok, when I select track my next privilege, it shows the top tag there (not very intuitive). [It also shows the rep gain there there for me.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IxANU.png)

Comment: Yes, and reputation gain is not the same as tag score gain ;) This case shows it.

Comment: In other words those +15 points of reputation are not +15 points to the tag score.

Comment: Yeah, the tooltip for the reputation gain says "Reputation gained on this tag since your last visit to the reputation tab". That doesn't change the fact that it shouldn't be there.

Comment: @TinyGiant, yes, but this is counter intuitive because of "top tag".

Comment: Technically it isn't counter-intuitive because it is showing you the _reputation gains_ in your top tag, not the tag score increase in that tag. As I said, I don't recall that number ever being there before, so something may have changed.

Comment: @TinyGiant, yes, but it should not be there.

Comment: @TinyGiant what's also curious in your screenshot is the fact that's not even the same number (204 vs 205).

Comment: @veve, yeah, not sure about that